# Errors when passing metadata into context in golang

Tags: go, grpc

I am working on specific with **handling GRPC requests**. I am trying to pass the meta from my GRPC request into the context based on this code sample: https://github.com/go-kit/kit/blob/master/auth/jwt/transport.go#L47.

(just in case, the contextKey explanation can be referred here: https://medium.com/@matryer/context-keys-in-go-5312346a868d#.vn10llkse):

Below is my code:

```
type contextKey string

func (c contextKey) String() string {
    return string(c)
}

var Headers := metadata.New(map[string]string{"auth":"", "abc": "", "xyz" : ""})

func ToGRPCContext() grpctransport.RequestFunc {
    return func(ctx context.Context, md *metadata.MD) context.Context {
       for _, header := range Headers {
           val, ok := (*md)[header]
           if !ok {
               return ctx
           }
           if len(val) > 0 {
              ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, contextKey(header), val)
           }
       }
       return ctx
    }

}
```

I am trying to read metadata fields (Headers) and pass it to the context.

I am getting the following errors. `cannot use header (type []string) as type string in map index` and `cannot convert header (type []string) to type contextKey`. I had fixed the above errors by accessing the index and doing something like this `val, ok := (*md)[header[0]]`. However, I want to pass all the elements of the map to the context.

Any suggestions on how to work around this problem?

Comment: If a header has multiple values, how do you want to pass those in? If you want to add them separately, just use a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the header name as the context key:

```
for name, header := range Headers {
  val := r.Header.Get(header)
  if len(val) > 0 {
    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, contextKey(name), val)
  }
}
```

Alternatively, store the headers as a single value:

```
ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, contextKey("headers"), Headers)
```

Comment: CeriseLimon: Do you have any suggestions for reading metadata for GRPC requests based on this: https://github.com/go-kit/kit/blob/master/auth/jwt/transport.go#L47 ?